# Mocks: How to avoid children talking to parents?

Tags: delphi, language-agnostic, mocking, delphi-5

i'm trying to test an object by passing a mock *owner*. Originally `PartD` would be passed a `PartB1` as its *owner*:

```
PartD partD = new PartD(partB1);
```

Now i want to test a feature of `PartD` by passing it a mock `owner`:

```
PartD partD = new PartD(mockPartB1);
```

This works okay, except there are things `PartD` does that depends on it knowing some statuses of some of its owners owners:

```
Boolean PartD.Validate()
{
    //Some fields are not required if the PartA has more than one transaction
    Boolean is24Hour = (this.PartB1.PartA.Transactions.Count > 1);

    if (this.Firstname == "")
    {
       if (!is24Hour)
           LogError("First name is empty");
       else
          LogWarning("First name is empty, but requires reasonable efforts");
    }

    ...
}
```

This causes my mock object problems because the `PartD` needs my mock to be of type `PartB1`, and it needs to implement a property called `PartA`, which needs to implement a property `Transactions`, which is a list with a `Count`.

i'm only interested in testing one part of one method in `PartD`, so i'm not really interested in re-designing an entire piece of software, surely introducing regressions, so i can test my 2 minute fix. i spent 2 minutes making the fix, and have now lost 6 hours trying to figure out how to test it:

```
PartD partd = new PartD(mock);
partD.HomeAddress = "123 Maïn Street";

CheckEquals(partD.HomeAddress, "123 Main Street");
```

> Even if i were willing to redesign the entire thing; passing down the `TransactionCount` to every child object, every time it changes seems like a horrible design. The `Validate` method, 3 children down, needing to know if there are other transactions isn't the only case in the system of a child needing to have information about its parents.
>
> If the parent objects passed down all this information down to all children, whether they needed it to not, is a waste - and prone to missing an update somewhere.
>
> Also, each time a child-child-child object has a new ***internal*** check, it have to re-design all objects around it - so they can all pass down information that may or may not be needed.

How can i avoid children talking to their parents as required, while not having parents giving child objects they don't want?

---

**Edit:** The change i'm waiting to test is:

```
if (Pos(homeAddress, "\r\n") > 0) ...
```

to

```
if (Pos("\r\n", homeAddress) > 0) ...
```

Comment: lol the title put me off, thought you were bullying children and their parents

Comment: Suddenly SO feels like an interpersonal psychology forum ...

Comment: i didn't know how to phrase it. Originally my question was going to involve `Parent donDraper = new Parent(grandpa);` and `Child sally = new Child(donDraper);`

Comment: i was chastised once with nerd rage, because i had a tag in the title. Changed title to *"Mock: ..."*

Comment: @Ian Boyd - I think the original title was only funny because sometimes the software terms we've developed using analogies collide in unintended ways. It's not like you made up the terms that you were using to make a pun - the new title is more obviously CS now.

Comment: @Ian Boyd - nothing makes me more nerd ragey than nerd rage.

Answer (score 1):

I think the method probably does need to be rewritten (or at least, refactored a bit); However, if you have control of the `partB1` class maybe a quick change that would make it easier to test would be to add a property to partB1 named `Is24Hour` that returns `PartA.Transactions.Count > 1`.  Then your mock can just return true or false for that particular property.

Obviously this only helps if you have a small number of these deep property accesses.

Comment: Logically, the construct makes no sense: A `PartB1` isn't something that is, or is not, "24-hour". It's the `PartA` is logically is 24-hour, by the virtue of it having more than one transaction. But i see how this hack can help me here, now.

Comment: Nah, i'm not going to do it. The objects are designed right. Passing information down is breaking the encapsulation. i know unit testing, dependency injection and mocks requires breaking encapsulation - but that doesn't mean i have to do it.